# How to install urllib3[secure] without pip

Tags: python

I have a old RHEL5 box running python 2.7 and I have to do a local install as the regular python site-packages are on a NFS filer I cannot write to.  I need to install urllib3 and according to this doc: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2 
I should execute:

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

But I cannot figure out how to get pip to install one of my local filesystems. I have done ...

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/apps/local_packages
```

But I do not know how to get the "secure" install using setup.py.

```
python setup.py install[secure] --prefix=/apps/local_packages
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Does installing the specified packages manually as mentioned in the doc you linked work?

Comment: Thanks I took a second look and it looks like it does.  I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `pip` by using `get-pip` from [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

And `[secure]` is using for install dependencies starting from 1.11 (2015-07-21) version

Comment: I have pip but I do not know how to tell pip to install onto my local filesystem instead of the site-packages that resides on the NFS filer that is read-only.

Comment: You can try use `--target <dir>` https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t

Comment: I can't install pip because of this issue.  What to do then?